# Different ways to run a syscall in assembly code without write int 0x80

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

It is an example of run the syscall sys_execve without int 0x80 in the assembly code, thus, my purpose is set the stack pointer register (ESP) address in EIP register. It is assumed that 0x80cd (int 0x80 = 0xcd80, but we need it in little endian) is in the top of the stack.

The register status before the code is:

```
*EAX  0xb
 EBX  0xffffd144 ◂— '/bin//sh'
 ECX  0xffffd13c —▸ 0xffffd144 ◂— '/bin//sh'
 EDX  0xffffd140 ◂— 0x0
 EDI  0x0
 ESI  0x0
 EBP  0x0
 ESP  0xffffd138 ◂— 0x80cd
*EIP  0x8049022 (_start+34) ◂— call   esp
```

In this moment I have the following (obviously, i know that variants of these code snippet with different registers are possible but using the same instructions):

1-

```
push esp
ret
```

2-

```
lea edi, [esp]
jmp edi
```

3-

```
call esp
```

I would like to know more code snippet to do this.

Comment: `lea edi, [esp]` is just `mov edi, esp` ... does that count as another way? You can also `jmp esp`.

Comment: I would like to find some ways without use these instructions... (jmp, lea, mov and call)

Comment: You got the `ret` version already. You could do something similar with `iret` too. Is self modifying allowed?

Comment: No, iret does not work in this case, but if i populate other registers like cs it should work (I have used iret to return from kernel land to user land). Anyway i would like to find instruction with opcode <80, ret and iret are CX.  thanks.

Comment: Put your actual constraints in the question.  There are a nearly unlimited number of ways to end up with `int 0x80` in memory somewhere that you ultimately jump to.  If you don't say what makes one variation interesting but another one not, it's pretty hard to answer.  Also put anything else you know, like if any register is pointing to a known location relative to the shellcode currently being executed. (That's the only way you could avoid an indirect jmp, call, or ret or similar, assuming you can't modify the IDT yourself before causing an interrupt. (You can't from user-space under an OS).)